# Import from one table in two tables where I need the auto-generated primary key in the second table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

followning scenario:

3 Tables

1 Table name,street,country,bank

This table needs to be imported to

Table1 Address(Primary Key Autoincrement ID),name,street,country

Table2 Address,bank

So I need the Address Value from the first insert for the second insert in table2

Database Server ist MSSQL 2008

Comment: Have you tried *anything at all*?

Comment: Look into the OUTPUT INTO clause of the insert command (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2183/using-insert-output-in-a-sql-server-transaction/)